# How do I connect to Azure SQL DB from VBA with Authentication = ActiveDirectoryInteractive?

Tags: excel, vba, azure-sql-database, ado

Set cnSQL = New ADODB.Connection
'cnSQL.Open "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server; Authentication = ActiveDirectoryInteractive; Database=XXXXX; Data Source=XXXX.database.windows.net"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you what you need.

You'll have to download the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and depending on your connection type you can update Authentication option

```
Sub AdoOdbcExample()    
    Dim con As Object    
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    con.Open _
            "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};" & _
            "Server=tcp:yourserver.database.windows.net,1433;" & _
            "Database=yourdb;" & _
            "Trusted_Connection=no;" & _
            "Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;" & _
            "UID=youremail;"
    con.Execute "UPDATE Clients SET FirstName='Gord' WHERE ID=5;"    
    con.Close    
    Set con = Nothing   
    'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated
    'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive
    'ActiveDirectoryPassword  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you login to https://portal.azure.com/ and then open up your azure sql database - not the server, you can find pre configured connection strings under "Settings" for various database connections like odbc:

**ODBC:**

- **ODBC (Includes Node.js) (SQL authentication)**
- `Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:yourserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=yourdb;Uid=yoursqluser;Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;`
- **ODBC (Includes Node.js) (Azure Active Directory password authentication)**
- `Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:yourserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=yourdb;Uid={your_user_name};Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword`
- **ODBC (Includes Node.js) (Azure Active Directory integrated authentication)**
- `Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:yourserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=yourdb;Uid={your_user_name};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated`

Please also note that for this scenario you also need the following drivers:

- **[Download ODBC driver 17 for SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)**

So in my case i used the following vba code with the copy paste odbc connection string (SQL authentication) from the azure portal.

```
con.ConnectionString = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:yourserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=yourdb;Uid=yoursqluser;Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
con.Open
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, this is the connection string that worked for me (Azure AD User + PW auth):

```
Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;User ID=myUserName;Password=myPassword;Use Encryption for Data=true;
```