# How do I connect to Azure SQL DB from CLASSIC ASP using Authentication ActiveDirectoryInteractive

Tags: azure, iis, azure-active-directory, vb6, azure-sql-database

I´m trying to do something similar to [How do I connect to Azure SQL DB from VBA with Authentication = ActiveDirectoryInteractive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213465/how-do-i-connect-to-azure-sql-db-from-vba-with-authentication-activedirectoryi) but using classic ASP on IIS.

I´ve tried the same solution, but the popup for user and password doesn´t appear.

Does someone know how to achieve this using classic ASP?

Thanks.

Comment: The Authentication ActiveDirectoryInteractive directs the system to use the Azure Active Directory interactive mode that supports Multi-Factor Authentication to connect to Azure SQL Database, you can refer to this link about [how to connect to Azure SQL Database with Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-directory-interactive-connect-azure-sql-db).

Comment: Thanks! As I can see using Microsoft ASP.NET it´s possible, but for classic ASP using VBScript maybe not. I will continue to do my research here and see if I can find something.

Comment: If you have any results, please share with us.

Comment: Has the problem been solved？