# Azure SQL Database with Access Frontend - Active Directory Authentication

Tags: ms-access, azure-active-directory, connection-string

I have a MS Access database serving as the frontend for an Azure SQL Server backend. I need to use both an ADO and an ODBC connection string for different functions (perform backend tasks, link frontend tables). I'm using Azure Active Directory Interactive authentication. The first time each of these connection strings is used in the frontend, it prompts the user to enter their Microsoft password (so the user is always entering the password twice - once for ADO, and again for ODBC). I've looked around for an answer but couldn't seem to find one - **I just want to allow the user to authenticate a single time for each session.**

There are other questions on SO about how to use Azure AD to connect Access to a SQL Server DB, but they don't answer this specific problem since I'm already connecting successfully.

I use a ConnectionString function to pass in "ADO" or "ODBC" depending on what I need. Here are the connection strings (both of them work).

```
Select Case connectionType
    Case "ADO":
        ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL19;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & serverName & ";" & _
                        "Initial Catalog=" & databaseName & ";" & _
                        "Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;" & _
                        "User ID=" & userEmail & ";" & _
                        "Use Encryption for Data=true;"
    Case "ODBC":
        ConnectionString = "ODBC;" & _
                        "DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;" & _
                        "SERVER=" & serverName & ";" & _
                        "DATABASE=" & databaseName & ";" & _
                        "UID=" & userEmail & ";" & _
                        "Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;" & _
                        "Encrypt=yes;"
End Select
```

I've tried changing the ODBC connection string to Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated (no password entry), but it doesn't work. In this scenario the users will NOT be able to just use their Windows credentials because of the way their company security is set up. I also can't use a hardcoded username/password in this case.

Any suggestions would be appreciated as this is functional but definitely a headache for users!

Comment: Maybe have user enter password in a textbox and concatenate that input to connection string with Password element. Specify ActiveDirectoryPassword instead of ActiveDirectoryInteractive. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect to Azure SQL DB from VBA with Authentication = ActiveDirectoryInteractive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213465/how-do-i-connect-to-azure-sql-db-from-vba-with-authentication-activedirectoryi)

Comment: @June7 That seems like a good solution - will check with the client if it works for them. I was avoiding users putting their password anywhere except the official Microsoft dialog but I think this will work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @June7 - you put me on track to come up with this solution. I used "ActiveDirectoryPassword" as the auth type but it kept throwing errors related to invalid credentials. I played around with some options and ultimately this solves the problem: use Interactive authentication for the first (ADO) connection, then use Integrated for the second (ODBC) connection. Since the user is authenticated after the first connection, the second one doesn't ask for any inputs.

```
Select Case connectionType
    Case "ADO":
        ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL19;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & serverName & ";" & _
                        "Initial Catalog=" & databaseName & ";" & _
                        "Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;" & _
                        "User ID=" & userEmail & ";" & _
                        "Use Encryption for Data=true;"
    Case "ODBC":
        ConnectionString = "ODBC;" & _
                        "DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;" & _
                        "SERVER=" & serverName & ";" & _
                        "DATABASE=" & databaseName & ";" & _
                        "UID=" & userEmail & ";" & _
                        "Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;" & _
                        "Encrypt=yes;"
End Select
```